# Automating SSH and running SCP and other commands in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scp

I am very new to scripting and have pretty less ideas on the options available and the usage.
My requirement is, I need to run a shell script from a jum host.
The script should copy a file from local to remote linux host, untar it and run a execute command. These three operations should happen on the remote machine but script will be run from the jump host.

I will pass destination machine IP and password and the file as the arguments.

I have tried to do this. But not able to succeed. Please some body help me out how i can accomplish this.

Comment: If you give root ( sudo) access for your destination PC, then you don't need to pass password.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass your password through the command line for these tools. Use private/public keys for password-less login. There are lots of examples on the internet on how to do this:

http://linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

Comment: Thanks Zhro.. I have seen this private/public key based authentication before posting this. In my requirement I will do ssh to 'n' remote machines but only once to run a small command over there. Anyways key based authentication requires to enter password atleast one time. I am looking for a way where in if i pass password as parameter, the shell script should take it and during ssh command it should not prompt me to enter the password again.